# How To Keep Posts from Being Displayed Two or More Times on My Homepage?

Tags: posts, pages, css

I'm trying to put together a news site with different news boxes on the homepage. The first news box at the top will have the top stories. The news boxes below it will have articles in specific categories like politics, entertainment, business, world, etc. I'd like the homepage to know to never display the same article twice so I won't have to waste time editing tags and categories ensuring it doesn't. What would be even better would be for the top news box to show only the most popular stories, and when a popular article jumps out of it's front page displayed catagory news box to no longer be shown in it, and vice versa when it jumps out of the most popular article news box.
Can this be written in the 'additional css' area?
I'm using a theme called Multinews. I've looked through its forum but didn't find anything to prevent this.
This is what's written in the theme's options for the homepage.
Can anything be written in here to prevent posts from being displayed twice? As it is now the newest article goes the first position in all three of these news boxes.

```
[newsbox style="nb3" number_of_posts="2" sub_categories="no" show_more="no" post_type="post"]

[newsbox style="nb6" number_of_posts="3" sub_categories="no" show_more="no" post_type="post"]

[newsbox style="nb4" number_of_posts="5" sub_categories="no" show_more="no" post_type="post"]
```

Comment: Questions regarding 3rd-party products are considered off-topic here, and would be best addressed in the official support channels for the product. It's unlikely that many have experience with this specific theme - but the theme's author and associated users definitely do ;)

Comment: I understand. I checked with the theme makers already. I didn't know if this was a basic WordPress/CSS solvable situation.

Comment: No worries! Really it sounds like you should see if the `newsbox` shortcode has an argument to skip over some posts in the other boxes. I.e. `number_of_posts="3" offset="2"` for the second box, or some such. It might be listed in theme's documentation - otherwise you'd have to ask in the theme's support, or look through the theme files for where the shortcode is defined. Another option might be to just use one newsbox and delete the other two, if you don't need them to be separate - then just bump the remaining one's `number_of_posts` up to `10`.